# Travis-ci: 'X' object has no attribute 'Y'

Tags: python, testing

**The issue was a typo, thanks everyone who tried to help**

I'm trying to run a unit test in travis-ci. At one point I have a class which simplified looks like this:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1

    def Y(self):
        return True

    def Z(self):
        return False

    def call_function(self, function):
        output = function(self.Y, self.Z, self.var1)
```

I then call `X.call_function`, which has given me no problems in the past when running the program. However, when running this in travis-ci I'm told:

> 'X' object has no attribute 'Y'

Strangely enough, it does not appear to have an issue with `self.Z`.

Does anybody know what causes this and how to fix it?

Update:
For clarity, the `function` parameter would be something like:

```
def function(func1, func2, var1):
    if type(var1) == int:
        func1()
    else:
        func2()
```

And then the main file would be something like:

```
x = X(3)
x.call_function(function)
```

Comment: all indents are right here? `call_function` is inside the class? if it is what happens to the `self`?

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar you're right, my example was incorrect, I've corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Your argument of self.Y returns the function itself, not the value it returns.
If instead your self.Y was set to `True`, the `call_function` function would work.
To run the function, you can put brackets after the function name.

Edit: Looks like you've forgotten about adding self. No worries, here's the working code. (The self argument is called automatically when you make an instance of a class. For more info on self, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self))

Edit 2: I've changed it so it returns the function. The self parameter is all that's needed.

Here's your fixed code:

```
class X:

    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1

    def Y(self):
        return True

    def call_function(self, function):
        output = function(self.Y, self.var1)
```

Comment: I don't wish to have the result, I want the function. In reality the function is called to verify if it was successful.

Comment: I've changed it so it returns the function. Did you want it differently?

Comment: This is exactly what I want and use, but Travis does not recognize `self.Y` as an attribute of `X`.

Comment: Could you give me an example of what `X.call_function` would take as the `function` parameter?

Comment: I'll add it to the post

Comment: I've added an example of `function`

Comment: It looks like your code works. I'm going to try to get it to not work...

Comment: Does your code do something along the lines of `x = X(1)`? When I run it, all is well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186042/discussion-between-geetransit-and-nathan).

Answer (score 1):

you have to add the self with the function  in class if it is not @static,class or abstract method

```
class X:

    def __init__(self,var1):
        self.var1 = var1

    def Y(self):
        return True

    def call_function(self, function):
        output = function(self.Y(), self.var1)
```

Comment: Thanks, my example was too much simplified, but the real thing does have that.